# Order of filter processing in CALCULATE

Tags: powerbi

Say I have a CALCULATE that looks as follows:

```
CALCULATE(    
            SUM('Sales Aggregated'[Total Sales]),
            ISBLANK('Customer Brand'[Age]),
            'Calendar'[Fiscal Week Description] IN {"Sep Wk 4 2021", "Sep Wk 3 2021"},
            'Customer Brand'[Brand First Purchase Date] IN VALUES('Calendar'[Fiscal Day Key])
        )
```

Are the filters guaranteed to be processed in the order entered? Or, is PBI smart enough to know that, in this case, the 4th filter must be processed after the 3rd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DAX, parameters are evaluated in the order they appear, with CALCULATE() and CALCULATETABLE() as exceptions.

For these two, the filters are evaluated first, after which the measure/calculation is executed. In your example, that means that the ISBLANK() is evaluated first, then the Fiscal Week Description and then the Brand First Purchase Date.

Read through the following article for more explanation:
[Order of Evaluation in CALCULATE](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/order-of-evaluation-in-calculate-parameters/)